# When deploying an ASP.MVC 3 application to a subfolder (not root), how do I handle routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I'm developing an ASP.MVC 3 project on my local computer where it is located at the root of the local web server.

```
localhost:12345/(project is here)
```

However, when I deploy to our public web server this application will be located in a subfolder

```
www.mycompany.com/myapp/(project goes here)
```

How do I deal with that mismatch? A few questions come to mind:

1. Do I need to adjust my MVC routes? Or will they just capture anything after /myapp/ ?
2. Do I use HomeController when I don't really want 'Home' to appear in the route? i.e. /myapp/home/(action)/(id) - rather I want this: /myapp/(action)/(id) if Home is the controller.
3. Should I match this folder structure on my local machine? (This project will never have access to anything outside that 'myapp' folder)
4. If 3 is yes, how?

I'm using VS 2010 with IIS Express locally.

Comment: can you put up some of your routes? and also confirm if the subfolder is a virtual directory.

Comment: I haven't changed the default ASP.MVC 3 project routes, but if you'd like I can post them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The routes are relative to the web application. Which means that you don't need to have /myapp/ in your routes.
2. No you don't need to have Home appear in the route. Personally as a practice I take out the default route.
3. No you don't need to match this folder structure.

Comment: That's what I like to hear! :-) I'll have to do some more testing before I can confirm this as an answer. Good idea about the default route.

Comment: How do you take out the Home from the route in #2?

Answer (score 2):

In our experience I found that within the Controllers there is no problem with the routes.

However, if you use HTML helpers within your views, like Html.BeginForm or Html.Action, these do not work with the overloaded methods that receive controller, action arguments.  You need to put the whole Url in the Html helpers using Url.Content,

This does not work:

```
Html.BeginForm()
```

or

```
Html.BeginForm("ResetPassword", "Account")
```

But this works:

```
Html.BeginForm(Url.Content("~/Account/ResetPassword");
```